# Concat in select formula - snowflake

Tags: sql, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when I use concat in select formula I will get concat of other column too.

**Example:**

```
SELECT
firstname,
surname,
concat(firstname,' ',surname) AS fullname
FROM
employee
```

**Source data:**

```
| firstname | surname |
| John      | Kenedy  |
```

**Output data:**

```
| firstname   | surname | fullname           |
| Kenedy John | Kenedy  | Kenedy Kenedy John |
```

Am I using concat wrog way?

Comment: Concat literally concatenates two strings. It's not doing a smart merge of any kind. If you wanted to merge it you'd have to check if the contents of one field already existed in the next first.

Comment: You're doing it right.   The output is indeed wrong.  Double check your source data.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you have a bad syntax this must be work

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname) as fullname FROM employee;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------+
| fullname        |
+-----------------+
| John Kenedy     |
| Abraham Lincoln |
+-----------------+
```

You can get more info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp)

Answer (score 1):

better still. don't use `concat` function.  Use the operator `||` instead.  If you use `concat()`, and you need to concatenate a bunch of things, it gets very ugly very quickly nesting all the concats within each other.

which do you prefer?

```
select concat('I ', concat('think ', concat('data ', concat('is ', 'fun '))))
```

-or-

```
select 'I ' || 'think ' || 'data ' || 'is ' || 'fun '
```

Comment: The `CONCAT()` function takes any number of parameters, so usage vs `||` is just a matter of taste.  I use both, but mostly `||`.  Depending on how Snowflake parses SQL, one of these alternatives may even be transformed into the other under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Your source data firstname column is not the same as your output data firstname column.  If  you were to run your concat function on the source data as you've presented it, then I believe you would get the results you expect.

## Edit 1: Removing duplicate words from a record with SQL

1. Use a `SPLIT_TO_TABLE` table function to split each part of the concatenation to an individual row
2. Use `QUALIFY` clause to filter out duplicate words for each flattened record
3. Grouping by the firstname and surname, use a `LISTAGG` function to concatenate together each unique word using an `ORDER BY` clause to preserve the order of the words

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_EMPLOYEE
AS
SELECT $1 AS FIRSTNAME
    ,$2 AS SURNAME
FROM VALUES 
('John','Kenedy')
,('Kenedy John','Kenedy')
;

WITH A AS (
  SELECT E.FIRSTNAME
      ,E.SURNAME
      ,STT.SEQ
      ,STT.INDEX
      ,STT.VALUE
  FROM TMP_EMPLOYEE E
      ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(FIRSTNAME || ' ' || SURNAME,' ') STT
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STT.SEQ,STT.VALUE ORDER BY STT.INDEX) = 1
)
SELECT A.FIRSTNAME
    ,A.SURNAME
    ,LISTAGG(A.VALUE,' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY A.INDEX) AS FULLNAME
FROM A
GROUP BY A.FIRSTNAME,A.SURNAME
;
```

**Notes**

- This does not compare any two or more records to each other to find duplicates

Comment: Then your issue is not with the `CONCAT()` function, but rather with trying to remove duplicate words from the output.  The `CONCAT()` or `||` function appends one or more values (of the same data type) to each other.  It DOES NOT parse the data in an attempt to remove duplicates.

I will amend my answer to provide a solution that should help.

Comment: There is a way to do this by building a stored procedure using javascript, but I have not written that as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake [CONCAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat) supports multiple arguments:

> Concatenates one or more strings, or concatenates one or more binary values. If any of the values is null, the result is also null.
>
> ```
> CONCAT( <expr1> [ , <exprN> ... ] )
> ```

[image]

The query works "as-is":

```
CREATE TABLE employee AS SELECT 'John' AS firstname, 'Kennedy' AS surname;

SELECT firstname,
       surname,
       concat(firstname,' ',surname) AS fullname
FROM employee;
```

Output:

| FIRSTNAME | SURNAME | FULLNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Kennedy | John Kennedy |

---

Sidenote: In the past CONCAT function supported only two arguments.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas - "Improve CONCAT function"